# Tell grunt to change image paths on build

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I need help telling grunt change the paths in the html as they differ in our production environment from the development.

Example:

```
Development: /images/image.jpg
Production: /different/path/images/image.jpg
```

Again, these are not in the scss files, they are in the html:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
```

when issuing 'grunt build' needs to change into:

```
<img src="/different/path/images/image.jpg">
```